# Colorful pixels overlaying launchpad icons

Tags: display, launchpad

Recently, when my external LG monitor is connected via Thunderbolt 3, a few apps in the launchpad are overlaid by some weird, colorful pixels. A restart often helps, but after some time this issue often pops up again. Only the presented apps are compromised by that error.

I'm using a MBP 13inch 2018 with 4 Thunderbolt ports and Touchbar running macOS Catalina 10.15.1 in dark mode.

Has anybody else experienced this issue as well?
[image: Screenshot]